# Creating an element node, setting its attributes, and appending the element?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

I am being instructed to create an element node for the link element and set its *rel* attribute to "styleSheet", its *id* attribute to "fancySheet", and its *href* attribute to "na_style_num.css" (where num is the value of the styleNum variable).

It then wants me to append the fancySheet style element to the document head.

I feel as if I'm *really* close or really far off here.  Here's what I've attempted without luck:

na_styler.js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setStyles);

function setStyles() {
   var styleNum = randInt(5);
   var styleNum = document.createElement("link");
   styleNum.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   styleNum.setAttribute("id", "fancySheet");
   styleNum.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + .css);
   document.head.appendChild(styleNum);
}
```

I've been receiving a few errors but the problem is it's written in a form I can't really understand.  For example:

*" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nt-test-3ed2ebdf.py", line 14, in  assert(link.get_attribute('id') == 'fancySheet'), 'The `id` attribute should be set to "fancySheet".  Actual: "' + str(link.get_attribute('id')) + '"'
AssertionError: The `id` attribute should be set to "fancySheet".  Actual: "" "*

Comment: missed quotes around `.css` in this line `styleNum.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + .css);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used same name for two variables. As they are are declared with `var` so it will not throw error. The second one will overwrite the first.

Just change the name of one of the variable

Also wrap `.css` in `""`

```
window.addEventListener("load", setStyles);

function setStyles() {
   var styleNum = randInt(5);
   var styleElm = document.createElement("link");
   styleElm.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   styleElm.setAttribute("id", "fancySheet");
   styleElm.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + ".css");
   document.head.appendChild(styleElm);
}
```

Comment: Please stop leaving comments about downvotes. These comments are just noise. If the person who downvoted had wanted to provide a more detailed explanation, they would have done so. They chose not to, which is completely fine. They're never going to see your comments.

Answer (score 1):

In line `styleNum.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + .css);` enclose `.css` in quotes, because it's a string and not a variable name.

`styleNum.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + '.css');`

```
window.addEventListener("load", setStyles);

function setStyles() {
   var styleNum = randInt(5);
   var styleEle = document.createElement("link");
   styleEle.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   styleEle.setAttribute("id", "fancySheet");
   styleEle.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + ".css");
   document.head.appendChild(styleNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The randomly generated number is meant to be stored in a variable separately from the element node. Since you use styleNum as the name of both variables, first a random number will be generated and stored in styleNum, then the new element node will be created and over right the randomly generated number, which is now lost forever since variables can't store two different values. To avoid this and keep the random number to use later in the function, you must name the element node being created anything other than `styleNum`

Here is an example of code which avoids this:

```
function setStyles() {
   var styleNum = randInt(5);
   var styleElementNode = document.createElement("link");
   styleElementNode.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   styleElementNode.setAttribute("id", "fancySheet");
   styleElementNode.setAttribute("href", "na_style_" + styleNum + ".css");
   document.head.appendChild(styleElementNode);
}
```

Notice also how I added the `" "` around `.css` and changed `styleNum` to `styleElementNode` in the function argument on the last line. This is because the function is meant to append the created element node, not the randomly generated number, to the document head.